# "Exception raised during rendering: column indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the column count. "

Tags: android, layout, android-gridlayout

I'm new to Android programming, and I'm trying to create a simple layout that has three items side by side.

I'm using a GridLayout to try to accomplish this. I created a GridLayout with three columns. Then I added three NumberPickers to it. When I did this, the `columnCount` went up to `4`. When I tried to change it back to 3, I got the error

`Exception raised during rendering: column indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the column count.`

This is strange. Why are the column indices exceeding the column count? Also, why do the columns end before they touch the right side of the screen?

[image: Android Screen]

**The XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/NumberPicker01"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/NumberPicker02"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/NumberPicker03"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_row="3" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Can you publish more details e.g. the layout xml file? Anything that helps to understand what you are doing in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I used your layout xml it placed three number below each other i.e. three rows. Picker 1 goes into row 0 and column 0. For Picker 2 and 3 you specify column 0 so they both go into a new row. In addition you have fill horizontal which would push any content to the right off the screen. Why do you have the space there? Finally you have the columnCount at 2. The column count should be three.

```
<GridLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="3"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/NumberPicker01"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/NumberPicker02"
    android:layout_column="1"/>

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/NumberPicker03"
    android:layout_column="2" />

</GridLayout>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

You can add space between the number pickers by adding margins.

Comment: Thanks, but there is still extra space on the right, after the last NumberPicker. Is there any way to center the three of them?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no attribute like layout_centerHorizontal. For the grid layout you could use two more columns: space at the left and the right, and the set the width of the spaces dynamically based on the screen size = a lot of work. You could use a relative layout and utilize layout_centerHorizontal for NumberPicker2. Then you place picker1 left and picker2 right of it.